# How to find Taylor or Laurent series of $z \mapsto \frac{z}{z^2-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I have the function

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{z^2-1}$$

I have to find Taylor or Laurent series of this function about the indicated point $z=2$. I tried to find Laurent series but looks like Taylor series will be much easier. So how can I find its Taylor series expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{z}{z^2 - 1} &= \frac{-z}{1-z^2}  \\
    &= \frac{1/2}{z+1} + \frac{1/2}{z-1}  \\
    &= \frac{1/2}{(z-2)+2+1} + \frac{1/2}{(z-2)+2-1}  \\
    &= \frac{1/2}{3--(z-2)} \cdot \frac{1/3}{1/3}+ \frac{1/2}{1--(z-2)}  \\
    &= \frac{1/6}{1-(-1/3)(z-2)} + \frac{1/2}{1--(z-2)}  \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6}(-1/3)^k(z-2)^k  +   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}(-1)^k(z-2)^k  \\
    &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{6}(-1/3)^k+\frac{1}{2}(-1)^k \right)(z-2)^k  \text{.}
\end{align*}

First, separate by partial fraction decomposition.  Then coerce every appearance of $z$ into the combination "$z-2$".  Rearrange the denominators to be of the form "$(\text{constant, preferably $1$})-(\text{term})$" and then scale the numerator and denominator so that the constant(s) are all $1$.  Now apply the standard geometric series to $\frac{c}{1-x}$.  Finally, collect by like powers of $z-2$.

Comment: I did same things until step 3. But im confused about the point z=2. Guess that I understood now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function's Laurent expansion around $z=2$ will just be a Taylor expansion since it's analytic at this point.

Comment: So do i have to try laurent series or taylor series?

Comment: Just a Taylor series.  If a function is analytic at a point (in this case $z=2$) then it will be equal to its Taylor series about that point with a radius of convergence equal to the distance of $z=2$ to the nearest singularity

Comment: the nearest singularity here being $z=1$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can compute the Laurent series. Nevertheless you can compute some termes : $$\frac{z}{z^2-1}=\frac{z-2}{(z-2)^2+4(z-2)+4}+\frac{2}{(z-2)^2+4(z-2)+4}.$$

Now, if $f(z-2)=\frac{(z-2)^2+4(z-2)}{4}$,  $$\frac{1}{f(z-2)+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^nf(z)^n,$$

whenever $|z-2|<1$. After, to compute $f(z-2)^n$ for all $n$ may be rather hard.

Comment: so that's why im trying to find taylor expansion

Comment: In your case, Laurent series and Taylor series coincides (the function is holomorphic in a neigborhood of 2) @KonstantinNovoselov

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $u=z-2$ and use partial fractions:
$$\frac z{z^2-1}=\frac{u+2}{(u+2)^2-1}=\frac{u+2}{(u+1)(u+3)}=\frac12\biggl(\frac1{u+1}+\frac1{3+u}\biggr).$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: I was seeking the method that Eric answered. I'm confused when I see z=2

Comment: It's almost the same, except I use $u=z-2$ as a variable from the beginning to ease the computations.

Comment: yes you are right. It looks less complex.